# Is it okay to ask about the functionality of a class?

Tags: discussion, questions, scope

I've had a problem with Delphi and Indy for several weeks and I ended up trying something random out of desperation, but now it works. The problem is, I have no idea why it works and I can't really find the reason in the documentation of either Delphi or Indy.

Can I ask something like "Why does x work?" or "Why doesn't x work without y?" or is that off-topic?

Comment: Well, if your stuff now works, and you cannot make it not work again, the we're all stuck.  We can't sensibly fix intermittent or heisenbugs over a blog.

Comment: See [*"programming by coincidence"*](https://pragprog.com/the-pragmatic-programmer/extracts/coincidence). If you don't even know what you changed and can't recreate the issue, we can't help with it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That, alone, is really a very broad question.  If you want to ask about it you should be clear about what you do and don't understand in the snippet in question.  Describe what you expected to happen, why you expected it to happen, what actually happened, and how that was different.  Adding all of this information narrows the scope of the question to a particular (or small number of) misconception(s) that you have.

You should also be describing what research you did into the related types/concepts.  Explain what you found, and why it fails to explain the behavior you're seeing (or what you don't understand about what you've found).